# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: yii

I am currently developing a web application using Yii Framework. When i hosted the application on Godaddy server i was facing an issue as

```
Error : CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections
```

I want to know how i can resolve this issue. It works fine on local server. Does there is a problem with my webserver or the database server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the error say?

> SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] **Too many connections**

The database has some limited number of connections it is willing to give out, and it has been reached. Consult the database documentation or the relevant sysadmins to see if you can get it increased, or if it is already large find out why you have hit the threshold.